# Open window of child process on the same screen as parent process

Tags: display

I have a lubuntu LTS 22.04 running on a laptop. I connect from a PC with SSH to the laptop to use the larger display. There is xmingw running as X display server.

I set at the bash prompt `export DISPLAY=mypc:0` and start applications, i.e. I don't use SSH to tunnel X. The windows of xload, xeyes, xedit, ... are open in xmingw successfully.

When I run `nemo` as file browser and use the context menu `Open with -> FeatherPad`, I expect that it inherits the DISPLAY variable from the parent process and opens the window on the same screen. But the FeatherPad window is open on the laptop's screen. The SSH session running nemo shows

```
qt.qpa.xcb: X server does not support XInput 2
failed to get the current screen resources
```

How can I successfully display the window on the desired screen?

I also tried to run `pcmanfm-qt` what doesn't show a window in xmingw at all. It just shows the two lines above on start.